# Virtual Hosts for external addresses on OSX 10.6

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost

I'm hosting my website on my own server running OSX 10.6.6. I have the main site up all fine with www2.chrislrobinson.co.uk pointing to my IP address (and hence the /Library/WebServer/Documents/ directory). My blog is located at www2.chrislrobinson.co.uk/blog but I would like to add to access it through blog.chrislrobinson.co.uk. My understanding is that I need to enable virtual hosts but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

So far, I've enabled the virtual host bit in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.
I've added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "Library/WebServer/Documents/blog"
ServerName blog.chrislrobinson.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

to `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and

```
127.0.0.1 blog.chrislrobinson.co.uk
```

to `/private/etc/hosts`. After restarting apache, not only does blog.chrislrobinson.co.uk not work, but I get the message

> **Forbidden**
>     You don't have permission to access /blog/ on this server.

I'd appreciate any help you guys can give.
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your httpd.conf for your Allow/Deny permissions.  You probably need to add a `<Directory /Library/Webserver/Documents/blog>` directive within the VirtualHost to allow accessibility.

Also, you're missing your leading / in the VirtualHost path.

Comment: Thanks for that. My `user/group` are both set to `_www` and everything now seems to work when I set the `ServerName` line in httpd.conf to `www2.chrislrobinson.co.uk:80`. However, using the above settings (albeit with the corrected leading /), `blog.chrislrobinson.co.uk` directs me to `www2.chrislrobinson.co.uk` (or `/Library/WebServer/Documents`). Am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: I assume in your vhosts.conf you have added/uncommented 'NameVirtualHost *', correct?  You could try moving ww2.chrislrobinson.co.uk to a vhost as well to see if it continues to override blog.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Server Admin for such a task. The reason is that it's not easier or better but if you make any changes from the command line, you will get Server Admin GUI out of sync with the real status of the configuration.
To solve your problem use Redirect Directive. More info is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575259/apache-redirect-blog-foobar-com-to-www-foobar-com

Comment: Sorry I should mentioned that I am running 10.6.6 client, not server. Can you recommend another GUI for server admin?

Comment: Oh, I was confused from your original post. Follow the link I sent you if you want to go the command line way. Otherwise install a control panel like Webmin, Plesk etc. Just google for it